# unident doesnt match any outer indent level, what do i need to change?

Tags: python, pygame, indentation

```
def update(self):
        # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
        # as a list of two numbers
         pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Fetch the x and y out of the list,
        # just like we'd fetch letters out of a string.
        # Set the player object to the mouse location
        self.circ.x=pos[0]
        self.circ.y=pos[1]
```

**Initialize Pygame**

right where the self.circ.x=pos[0] is there seems to be a unident/indentation error, i am new to python and was wondering what was wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have a whitespace before pos variable delete it.

```
def update(self):
    # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
    # as a list of two numbers
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Fetch the x and y out of the list,
    # just like we'd fetch letters out of a string.
    # Set the player object to the mouse location
    self.circ.x=pos[0]
    self.circ.y=pos[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pos is located one far too right.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
         pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

has an extra space. To see that clearly, removing the comments helps.

```
         pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.circ.x=pos[0]
        self.circ.y=pos[1]
```